# Movie where a monster enter's a man's butt when he goes to the toilet

Tags: story-identification, movie

All I remember is that it takes place in a cabin in the snow, in one scene a man goes into the toilet and a monster enters the cabin through the toilet, the monster kills the man by entering his butt and later in the movie they found his body (the man) sitting on that toilet.

I believe the title has the word "Dream" in it but I could be wrong.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This sounds like the sci-fi film "Dreamcatcher", based on the novel by Stephen King. This is an alien invasion movie. The aliens appear in three forms: A fungus mold, a typical grey alien, and a weasel-like creature, one of which gestates in a man's colon and emerges from his rectum while he's on the toilet. The story takes place during winter.

[image]

You can see the trailer on Youtube

Comment: "Byrum are red, lamprey-like creatures with multiple rows of razor-sharp teeth; a second form of byrus grows on open wounds and mucus membranes. When an infestation is sufficiently established, the host develops a form of telepathy with other infested individuals. The friends name the byrum "shit weasel" because it exits the body through the anus, killing the host. "  - from the Dreamcatcher page on [the Stephen King Wiki](https://stephenking.fandom.com/wiki/Dreamcatcher)